# Meaning of * and . in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't understand the use of `e.*`, `at_firstname.value` in this query:

```
SELECT e.*
     , at_firstname.value AS firstname 
  FROM customer_entity AS e 
 INNER 
  JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS at_firstname 
    ON (at_firstname.entity_id = e.entity_id) 
   AND (at_firstname.attribute_id = '5') 
 WHERE (e.entity_type_id = '1') 
   AND (at_firstname.value = 'sander') 
 ORDER 
    BY e.email ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you mean

```
 SELECT e.*, at_firstname.value AS firstname 
  FROM  `customer_entity` AS `e`
  INNER JOIN at_firstname   ON
    at_firstname.entity_id = e.entity_id AND at_firstname.attribute_id = '5'
  WHERE e.entity_type_id = '1' AND at_firstname.value = 'sander' ORDER BY e.email ASC
```

e is an alias of the table  customer_entity   (`customer_entity` AS `e` ) so e.* mean all the columns of the table customer_entity.

at_firstname.value  seems an error because the join condition need  the table name only and not  the table.column

anyway the sintax at_firstname.value AS firstname  mean that the tablename.columnname is show using the alias firtsname  for the column

Otherwise if the original query is right the at_firstname.value AS firstname 
is an alias for the table alias  at_firstname (column name value) for the database at_firstname and the table value

PS don't use unuseful ()  around condition when not need

Answer (score 0):

With `e.*`you select all columns from table `e`.
With `at_firstname.value` just column `value` from table `at_firstname`.

Comment: e.* selects all COLUMNS, it has nothing to qualify how many rows